# FullCalendar do not show event blocks and instead display a customized text?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, frontend

is there a way to hide or not to display event blocks and at the same time use a customized text?[image]

Comment: You just want text on the calendar instead of events?  Some CSS could make the text look the way you want

Comment: @EatPeanutButter that is correct, but I want a diferent text on specific dates only.

Comment: Add them as events.  That's what a calendar is for.  You can customize the appearance of events individually if you'd like. Docs are here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Like EatPeanutButter says I can customize the appareance of events with eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(element);
            element.text("a bigger text for this object, you can modify element as you want now with another label");
        },
```